# Are non-printable characters supposed to appear with CDC::DrawText?

Tags: mfc, windows-ce, gdi, drawtext

If I have a string with non-printable characters, are they supposed to appear or not when I use CDC::DrawText?

```
CString str = L"ItemOne\x1EItemTwo\x1EItemThree\x1E";
```

In WinCE5, the non-printable character did not appear, but in WinCE7, it appeared as a square. Which one has the correct behavior?

Or does it depend on the font used, or perhaps it is something that is configurable in the OS?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the font and on the charset you're using in the OS.
Don't forget that Windows CE is natively unicode, so something like \x1E is translated into Unicode too.